# python3 how to write to a sqlite3 database in a thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a fastapi server that can have several clients connecting to it. It seems that every time you visit the site will it kick off a different thread on the server computer. I am trying to find a way to write to a sqlite3 database that will only require me to open the database once. If there is a better solution than what I said please let me know.

main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
import Database
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

Database_obj = Database.Database_Sqlite3()



# This class is to allow me to control the input for the data_from_client function. This will be inputed into the computer table in the database
class Computer(BaseModel):
    uuid: str
    computer_name: str
    public_ip: str
    date: str

@app.post("/test")
def data_from_client(computer: Computer):
    try:
        # This does not seem very efficent and I am not sure that this will work when several clients start connecting. This requires the database to be opened and closed
        # every time you need to write and fastapi will allow the clients to connect in different threads. 
        Database_obj.safe_start()
        Database_obj.write_computer_table(uuid=computer.uuid, computer_name=computer.computer_name, public_ip=computer.public_ip, date=computer.date)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True)
```

Database.py

```
import sqlite3
import os
import mysql.connector


class Database_Sqlite3:

    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = None
        self.cursor = None
        self.database = r"database.db"
        # This setting will not always do what I want. This will create the Data directly from the location of your terminal not the location of the application. I will need to come up with a better way for this.
        self.path = "./Data"

    def make_local_directory(self):
        is_dir = os.path.isdir(self.path)
        if not is_dir:
            try:
                os.mkdir(self.path)
                return 0
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                return 1
        else:
            return 0

    def start_database(self):
        try:
            full_database_path = os.path.join(self.path, self.database)
            self.connection = sqlite3.connect(full_database_path)
            self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
            return 0
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return 1
    
    def safe_start(self):
        try:
            self.make_local_directory()
            self.start_database()
            return 0
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return 1

    def create_computer_table(self):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE computer (uuid text, computer_name text, public_ip text, date text)''')
            return 0
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return 1

    def write_computer_table(self, uuid, computer_name, public_ip, date):
        data = (uuid, computer_name, public_ip, date)
        self.cursor.execute('INSERT INTO computer VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)', data)
        self.connection.commit()
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use SQLite? It does have a very limited support for concurrency. Why not use PostgreSQL or other RDBMS that's actually designed with concurrency in mind?

Comment: @pavel I thought it was going to be the easiest option. This is my first ever sql project to allow me to practice. Is there one you would recommend? I am looking for something that is not super complex to setup and has good integration with python3.

Comment: You can still try to do it with SQLite using `BEGIN CONCURRENT` statement: https://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/doc/begin-concurrent/doc/begin_concurrent.md#:~:text=Usually%2C%20SQLite%20allows%20at%20most,system%20still%20serializes%20COMMIT%20commands.